# serializing radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of radio buttons like this

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="h" />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="g" />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="s" />
```

Now I am serialzing the form to save their values, next time from the saved serialized form values  I want load these radio buttons correctly, but its not showing the selected radio button correctly.

I am showing the form's serialized values into the page like this

```
var obj = $('form').serializeObject();
    for(var r in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(r)){
                var nr = obj[r];
                $('[name='+r+']').val(nr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: we need more information

Comment: What code are you using to serialise them? What code are you using to load them? Telling us that "its not showing the selected radio button correctly" when you don't tell us what it is doing or what "it" is, isn't helpful.

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-serializeobject-plugin

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```html
<form id="foo">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="h" />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="g" />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="s" />
    <button id="button">foo</button>
</form>

<form id="bar">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="h" />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="g" />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="s" />  
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var foo = $('#foo').serializeArray();
        for(var i in foo) {
            if(foo.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                $('[name="'+foo[i]['name']+'"][value="'+foo[i]['value']+'"]').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                })
            }
        }
    })    
})();
```